# Div should not be over Div with background image with divs inside

Tags: css, html

Div should not be over Div with background image with divs inside, but for some reason the about div is displayed over the nav:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*background-color: blue;*/
}

.divider {
  background-color: #be2b27;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

.divider h1 {
  font-family: "Nexa Light";
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  text-align:left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.lorem-text {
  font-family: "Menlo";
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: white;
}

.start-section {
   margin-top: 30px;
   /* position: absolute; */
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-top: 20px;
}


#start-bg {
  background-image: url(water.jpg);
  background-color:#9abee1;
  background-repeat: round;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#home-head {
  font-family: 'Nexa Light';
  /* font-size: ; */
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.nav { }
```

```html
<div id="start-bg">
  <!--<div class="nav"...>...</div>-->
  <div class="start-section">
    <h1 id="home-head">Landing Page</h1>
    <p class="lorem-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ornare est in maximus vestibulum.
    Mauris eu tincidunt quam.<br> In commodo neque id tortor mattis, non consectetur ante tincidunt.
    Nunc ultrices ultricies purus, id finibus justo eleifend sit amet.<br>
    Sed in iaculis libero, et gravida nibh.
    Proin mollis, nibh eu rhoncus scelerisque, orci ex posuere mi, id pharetra purus est suscipit sapien.
    Aliquam fermentum dignissim ultricies. Cras vitae neque tincidunt, tristique neque at, ornare leo.<br>
    Integer gravida lectus sed venenatis auctor. Vestibulum sed ligula eget dui ultrices luctus.<br>
    Etiam dapibus auctor sollicitudin. Nam vel dui non lorem semper scelerisque. Donec sed condimentum mauris.
    Maecenas ac enim sit amet orci sodales porta.
    </p>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><br>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divider">
  <h1>About</h1>
</div>
```

There must be something wrong with the positions or something or the fact that when the div has a background image it is not registered as holding any content so the about div is displayed above it.

What do I need to do?

I want the div to be displayed after the background image ends and stays there when I remove the images. If you need the nav html and css code i will give it to you.

Comment: yep... definitely HTML and specially CSS for the nav bar would make for a better formed question

Comment: U sure, i removed the nav bar and it doesnt make a difference

Comment: I want the about to go under the the blue bit like it is in the html

Comment: @Tom Please create a [mcve].

Comment: try to better explain the issue. Which div is displaying over which other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#start-bg {
background-image: url(water.jpg);
background-color:#9abee1;
background-repeat: round;
height:100%;
position: absolute;
}
```

If you remove:
position: absolute;
Red bar go to bottom bottom of the page.

Comment: nice, but now there is a white bar at the top how do remove this?

Comment: I have blue background, but mayby **.start-section {
   margin-top: 30px;** this is problem ;)